# Help checking an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to show that
$$
T = \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}t - \frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{4c^2b^2}[1 - \exp(-2c^2b^2t)]
$$
is non-negative (i.e. $T\geq 0$), if it is, where $a,b,c,t>0$ and $a>b$.

---

My initial thoughts:
\begin{align}
T &= \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}t - \frac{(a^2-b^2)}{4c^2b^2}[1 - \exp(-2c^2b^2t)]\\
&= \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}t - \frac{(a^2-b^2)}{4c^2b^2} + \underbrace{\exp(-2c^2b^2t)}_{<1}\frac{(a^2-b^2)}{4c^2b^2}\\
&> \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}t - \frac{(a^2-b^2)}{4c^2b^2} 
\end{align}
which is not so helpful.

Comment: Show that the derivative of $T$ wrt to $t$ is greater than zero for all $t>0$. This proves the result you want, since $T=0$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @Marc That's way better than what I was trying to do... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $$f(t)=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}t-\frac{a^2-b^2}{4b^2c^2}(1-e^{-2b^2c^2t})$$
thus $$f'(t)=1/2\, \left( {a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) t-1/4\,{\frac { \left( {a}^{2}-{b
}^{2} \right)  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{-2\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}t}} \right) }{{c}^
{2}{b}^{2}}}
$$
thus $$f'(t)=0$$ if $$t=-1/2\,{\frac {1}{{c}^{2}{b}^{2}}\ln  \left( {\frac {{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}{{
a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}} \right) }
$$

Answer (score 0):

As Marc noted, just see that
$$
\frac {\partial T} {\partial t}
=
\frac{1}{2}\left[ a^2 + b^2 + (-a^2 + b^2)\underbrace{\exp(-2b^2c^2t)}_{<1} \right] > \frac{1}{2}[a^2+b^2 - a^2 +b^2] 
$$
so $\partial_t T > 0$.

---

However, another way is to show it increases with $c$.
Well : $$
\lim_{c \rightarrow 0} T = \frac {a^2 + b^2} {2} t - \frac {a^2 - 
      b^2} {2} t = b^2 t > 0
$$
But then
$$
\frac {\partial T} {\partial c} =
 \frac {(a - b) (a + b)\exp (-2 b^2 c^2 t)[\exp (2 b^2 c^2 t) - 1 - 
      2 b^2 c^2 t]} {2 b^2 c^3}
$$
which has $\partial_c T > 0$ because $e^x \geq 1 + x$.